# Python: How to continue a nested for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying loop through a dict which has an unknown number of nested layers.

I want to write a function which loops through each layer until the very end.

I believe a recursive function is required here but I would like some advice on how to do it.

here's the code logic:

```
for levelone in file:
    for leveltwo in levelone:
        for levelthree in leveltwo:
            for levelfour in levelthree:
                ....
```

What do you guys think?

Comment: Could you be more specific what you mean? Do you want to continue levelthree? How do you know how many loops are _available_?

Comment: seems you are asking for breaking out

Comment: Are you asking how you can process an unspecified number of nested lists/iterables?

Comment: Yes exactly, I would like to know how many more nested loops are available.

Comment: Is it a dict or something that looks like a dict? I notice you have `for levelone in file` so are you reading something? Is it json perhaps?

Comment: You need to be clearer; do you have a sequence of iterables and you want to produce their product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this recursively you need to test each value to see if it's also a dict, which is a bit ugly in python and probably not very efficient. If it is, you call the function again on it and combine that return with what we have so far. If it's not a dict, you're at the bottom layer and can do whatever you'd like with the value.

```
def recurseDict(nested_dict):
    output = []

    for key, value in nested_dict.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value,dict):
            output = output + recurseDict(value)
        else:
            # Do whatever you want here, I'll just add the values to a list
            output.append(nested_dict[key])
    return output
```

Sample input and output:

```
In [28]: a = {'blue': 4, 'green': {'yellow': {'black': 16}}, 'red': 3}

In [29]: recurseDict(a)
Out[29]: [4, 16, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is this:

```
def loop_through(iterable):
    try:
        for item in iterable:
            # do your thing
            loop_through(item)
    except TypeError:
        # not iterable, reached the bottom
```

Once you've put the appropriate functionality in, you can `loop_through(file)`. Depending on what you want to do, you might need to `return` something from the recursive calls and deal with it, or create a container to put the results in:

```
def loop_through(iterable, container=None):
    if container is None:
        container = []
    try:
        for item in iterable:
            # do your thing
            loop_through(item, container)
    except TypeError:
        # not iterable, reached the bottom
```

Comment: Your solution is more modular than mine with the container. Would the try/except here be considered more pythonic, do you think?

Comment: I would generally prefer `try: except:` in these cases; it allows you to work with any iterable (list, dict, tuple, set, ...) or object that supports the appropriate behaviour (without necessarily being a `dict` subclass) rather than explicitly checking for one of them.

Comment: True, but if you have to be doing manipulation of values in a dict you have to do more than just iterate through them eventually.

Comment: @Decency, you were given a good skeleton; you may expand it from here

Comment: In this specific case I would still rather use `try: item[key]`, because then any object that implements `__getitem__` will work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `break`.

```
for levelone in file:
    for leveltwo in levelone:
        for levelthree in leveltwo:
            for levelfour in levelfive:
                break # Continue levelthree iterations.
```